# error occurred while installing ruby-debug-ide, but only in docker compose build

Tags: ruby-debug-ide

If I install the ruby-debug-ide Gem by

1. `docker compose run app bash`
2. `gem install "ruby-debug-ide"`

it installs without issue.

If I install the ruby-debug-ide Gem by

1. `docker compose run app bash`
2. Add ruby-debug-ide to my Gemfile
3. `bundle install`

it installs without issue.

After that second attempt there are changes (as expected) to bit my Gemfile and my Gemfile.lock. If I now run `docker compose build` it crashes out with this error:

> #10 14.40 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> #10 14.40
> #10 14.40     current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.3/ext
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb
> #10 14.40 Installing base gem
> #10 14.40 Building native extensions. This could take a while...
> #10 14.40 Building native extensions. This could take a while...
> #10 14.40 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> #10 14.40
> #10 14.40     current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/debase-0.2.5.beta2/ext
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
> #10 14.40 ./siteconf20220331-401-hxgkmc.rb extconf.rb
> #10 14.40 checking for vm_core.h... no
> #10 14.40 checking for vm_core.h... no
> #10 14.40 **************************************************************************
> #10 14.40 No source for ruby-3.1.1-p18 (revision
> 53f5fc4236a754ddf94b20dbb70ab63bd5109b18)
> #10 14.40 provided with
> #10 14.40 debase-ruby_core_source gem. Falling back to ruby-3.1.0-p0.
> #10 14.40 **************************************************************************
> #10 14.40 checking for vm_core.h... yes
> #10 14.40 checking for iseq.h... no
> #10 14.40 checking for iseq.h... yes
> #10 14.40 checking for version.h... yes
> #10 14.40 creating Makefile
> #10 14.40
> #10 14.40 current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/debase-0.2.5.beta2/ext
> #10 14.40 make DESTDIR= clean
> #10 14.40
> #10 14.40 current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/debase-0.2.5.beta2/ext
> #10 14.40 make DESTDIR=
> #10 14.40 compiling breakpoint.c
> #10 14.40 compiling context.c
> #10 14.40 Assembler messages:
> #10 14.40 Fatal error: can't create context.o: No such file or directory
> #10 14.40 make: *** [Makefile:246: context.o] Error 1
> #10 14.40
> #10 14.40 make failed, exit code 2
> #10 14.40
> #10 14.40 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/debase-0.2.5.beta2 for
> #10 14.40 inspection.
> #10 14.40 Results logged to
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/bundle/extensions/aarch64-linux/3.1.0/debase-0.2.5.beta2/gem_make.out
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in `run'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:44:in` block in make'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in `each'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in` make'
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in
> `block in   #10 14.40 build'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in` open'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in
> `build'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in` build_extension'
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `block in   #10 14.40 build_extensions'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in` each'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `build_extensions'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in` build_extensions'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:328:in `install'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:104:in`   install'
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:279:in `block in   #10 14.40 install_into'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:271:in` each'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:271:in `install_into'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:147:in` install'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:252:in
> `install'   #10 14.40   mkrf_conf.rb:31:in` rescue in '
> #10 14.40   mkrf_conf.rb:24:in `<main>'   #10 14.40    #10 14.40 rake failed, exit code 1   #10 14.40    #10 14.40 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.3   #10 14.40 for inspection.   #10 14.40 Results logged to   #10 14.40 /usr/local/bundle/extensions/aarch64-linux/3.1.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.3/gem_make.out   #10 14.40    #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in` run'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/rake_builder.rb:11:in `build'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in` build_extension'
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `block in   #10 14.40 build_extensions'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in` each'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `build_extensions'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in` build_extensions'
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in
> #10 14.40 `build_extensions'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in`   install'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:204:in `install'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in`   install'
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
> #10 14.40 `install_from_spec'   #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in   #10 14.40` do_install'
> #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
> #10 14.40 `block in worker_pool'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in` apply_func'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'   #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in` loop'
> #10 14.40   /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'   #10 14.40 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in` block (2 levels) in
> #10 14.40 create_threads'
> #10 14.40
> #10 14.40 An error occurred while installing ruby-debug-ide (0.7.3), and Bundler cannot
> #10 14.40 continue.

(Sorry about the long copy-and-paste, I am not sure which part is relevant.)

The part of my Dockerfile that does the actual building is this:

```
FROM ruby:3.1-slim-bullseye as builder
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade --yes \
    && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential curl git gnupg firefox-esr \
  && curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x bullseye main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends nodejs yarn \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/lib/apt/archives/*.deb
ENV TZ='Europe/London'
ENV RUBYOPT='-W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental'
ENV PATH="$PATH:node_modules/.bin"
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/
RUN bundle install --jobs 4 \
    && bundle binstubs --all --path /usr/local/bundle/bin
```

Why can I build at a bash prompt in the container but cannot when rebuilding the container?